# Camel AWS S3 Cron Schedule

Tags: amazon-s3, cron, apache-camel

I am using the aws-s3 component to consume some files, I want to do this using a schedule with a cron expression, this is what I am trying:

```
    from("aws-s3://myBucketName?" +
            "accessKey=*******&" +
            "secretKey=********&" +
            "prefix=myFiles&" +
            "deleteAfterRead=false&" +
            "scheduler=quartz2&" +
            "scheduler.cron=0+0/1+*+1/1+*+?+*")
```

However I am getting this error:

```
There are 1 scheduler parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. 
Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are
properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{cron=0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *}]
```

I've also tried URLEncoding the cron expression but it didn't help.

What am I missing? Is the s3 component incompatible with the scheduler?

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Hi Claus, I'm using 2.16.2

Comment: It could be a bug, I haven't dived into this. You can log a ticket, or try to ping me tomorrow on the irc chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug in `camel-aws` which I have reproduced and have a fix in the works.

I logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9686

Should be fixed in the next release.